# Cakephp - get names function

Tags: cakephp

> am developing an app plugin on cakephp. And i am stuck on a function,
>   demo bellow:
>
> In the database i have a table "platforms" with data ('1' => 'PC', '2'
>   => 'PS3' ...).
>
> In games view, i have:
>
> ```
> <? 
> $platformes = array($igra['Igra']['pid']); /* gives me 1,2 */
> $platforme = $this->requestAction(
>     array(
>         'plugin' => 'gamer', 
>         'controller' => 'Igra', 
>         'action' => 'getPlatformaIme'
>     ),
>     $platformes
> ); 
> ?>
> ```
>
> In controller i have a function like this:
>
> ```
> function getPlatformaIme($pids) {
>     $platforme =  explode(', ', $pids);
>     $this->loadModel('Gamer.Platforme');
>
>     foreach($platforme as $pid) {
>         $this->Platforme->find('all', array(
>             'conditions' => array('Platforme.id' => $pid)
>         ));
>         $name[] = $this->Platforme->field('name');
>     }
>
>     return implode(', ', $name);
> }
> ```
>
> This should give me PC, PS3, but it doesn't. It gives me PC, even if
>   there is no 1 in array. How can i fix my function to work?

Tnx for the help, here is the correct way to do it.

the function:

```
function getPlatformaIme($pids) {
    $platforme[] =  explode(',', $pids);
    $this->loadModel('Gamer.Platforme');

    foreach($platforme as $pid) {
    $names = $this->Platforme->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Platforme.id' => $pid
        )
    ));
    }

    return implode(', ', $names);
}
```

This gives the names from the db, if array is (1,2) returns (PC, PS3)

Comment: I have no idea what’s going on here. Are you asking and answering your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Refer to the documentation

A [find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find) returns data, it doesn't modify the object's state. If the return value of a find is not used, it's issuing an sql query for no reason/benefit.

[field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field) expects *either* conditions to be passed, or it will read the field value for the current model id. In the question there are no conditions and the model doesn't have an id set - as such, effectively, a random record's name field will be returned multiple times (probably the same name, but not necessarily).

### Corrected code without changing logic:

The code in the question can be corrected as follows:

```
function getPlatformaIme($pids) {
    $platforme =  explode(', ', $pids);
    $this->loadModel('Gamer.Platforme');

    foreach($platforme as $pid) {
        $this->Platforme->id = $pid;
        $name[] = $this->Platforme->field('name');
    }

    return implode(', ', $name);
}
```

Using `field` there's no need to call find also. This will return an array like so:

```
array(
    'One',
    NULL, # <- if the pid doesn't exist
    'Three'
)
```

### Use an appropriate find

The above is not the most logical way to get an array of names, [find('list')](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) exists for this kind of use case:

```
function getPlatformaIme($pids) {
    $platforme =  explode(', ', $pids);
    $this->loadModel('Gamer.Platforme');

    return $this->Platforme->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'id' => $pids
        )
    ));
}
```

This will return an array like so:

```
array(
    1 => 'One',
    3 => 'Three'
)
```

### requestAction isn't necessary

Instead of using request action invoking a request, to call a controller, to call a model - the model can be called directly:

```
// anywhere
$names = ClassRegistry::init('Gamer.Platforme')->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $pids
     )
 ));
```

Without caching elements, such code should *not* be in the view. Rather in a beforeRender function, otherwise it's very easy to write unmaintainable applications.

However, given the code in the question it's one alternative.

Comment: Tnx for this fix, but even with my code, i get the desired array into the function. Its the function, that gives me the wrong data.

Comment: Then -1 as there is a lot of irrelevant code, and "the question" is not clear.

Comment: $name[] = $this->Platforme->field('name'); - it allways returns the PC, even if there is no '1' in the array, coult it be, that it picks the wrong data?

Comment: i changed your function a bit, and it works. Tnx for the info, i will try to use it in my coding.